# How to group Azure deployment events into a single alert e-mail

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid, azure-monitoring

I want to send a single alert on a successful deployment in Azure. Alerting on individual events is a problem because that could get too noisy.

Grouping events by their correlation id and sending that in a single e-mail would be great. Sort of like what you might find in the deployment overview page in the Azure portal:

```
Your deployment is complete

Deployment name: mesh_rp.linux
Subscription: AcmeDevTest
Resource group: rg-mesh-demo

Start time: 11/29/2018 9:00:00 AM
Duration: 2 minutes 56 seconds
Correlation ID: 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111

Resource              TYPE                                         STATUS
HelloWorldApp         Microsoft.ServiceFabricMesh/applications     OK 
HellowWorldNetwork    Microsoft.ServiceFabricMesh/networks         OK
```

How would I go about grouping those events by their correlation id and then firing that off in an e-mail?

Is this possible with Azure Monitor or is something like logic apps and event grid the way to go here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Monitor would be best for you.

1. From Azure portal, select **Monitor** > **Alerts**
2. Click **New Alert Rule** at the top of the **Alerts** window.
3. Configure **Alert target** and **Target criteria**
4. Configure **Action group** to send an email.

For a successful deployment, you should choose "create new deployment" as the target criteria.

For more details, please refer to the following:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/alert-activity-log